# What is the path of "SysWOW64" when "Load User Profile" True for Application Pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I've already looked up in existing question library but havn't get an answer to my question. Below are my details.

1. I have a ASP.NET web site requires some 32-bit dlls. Since it is being hosted on a 64-bit system, usually I copy all 32-bit dlls to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" so it works well.
2. Now I don't want to copy anything to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" so I take the solution set "Load User Profile" as True in IIS. My Application Pool Identity is "sawyer"
3. I believe there must be some folder where I should copy my 32-bit dlls to. It is under "c:\users\sawyer". But I don't know exactly which subfolder it is. I tried below addresses but got no luck for now.

> --c:\users\sawyer
>
> --c:\users\sawyer\SysWOW64
>
> --c:\users\sawyer\Windows\SysWOW64
>
> --c:\users\sawyer\AppData\Local\Temp\SysWOW64
>
> --c:\users\sawyer\AppData\Local\Temp\Windows\SysWOW64

4. Question: Which folder it should be?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if I need to provide any other information.

Comment: Copying your own DLLs into the windows system directories? What is this, the 90s? Why is "your website's own bin folder" not the correct answer?

Comment: Thank you for comment. If no 32-bit dlls needed, my own website's bin folder is enough. But if 32-bit dlls needed, it is also required to copy to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever has pointed out a bin folder is the normal manner of doing this.

Comment: Appreciate your answer too. I already copied to bin folder. 32-bit dlls have to be copied to both bin folder and "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".

Comment: Could it be that you just need to change your application pool to run as a 32 bit application?

Comment: Thank you for attention! I already set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" in IIS. I think it is not the reason.

Comment: This issue has been addressed following below two steps:
1. Add "Path" pointing to my web site's bin folder
2. Go to IIS, find the Application Pool, hit the "Recycle"